# I'm trying to make a circle in my array / image but it turns into a line

Tags: python, image

I have an image.
I want to make a large white circle in the center of the image and then show it. If i run the code a large white line comes and not a circle.
[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZCDW.png)

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open("C:\TMP\Lily1.jpg")
img = img.convert("L")
Img = np.array(img)

def Show(arr):
    img = Image.fromarray(arr, "L")
    img.show()

def Dis(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return ((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) ** 0.5

sx = len(Img[0]) / 2
sy = len(Img) / 2

Canvas = np.array(Img, copy = True)

for a in range(int(sy * 2)):
    for b in range(int(sx * 2)):
        if Dis(sx, b, sy, a) < 200:
            Canvas[a, b] = 255

Show(Canvas))
```

This is my code.

Answer (score 0):

Because you made an error in the `Dis` function call.

Following the function signature of `Dis`,

```py
Dis(sx, b, sy, a)
```

Should be:

```py
Dis(sx, sy, b, a)
```